# Passing the Windows user to a string in Access

Tags: windows, string, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is there a way of passing Windows log in information to a string in Access? I need a way of automatically detecting a user on a multi-user database held in a central location. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks - will look into both answers and report back on which works the best,

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I use on a domain network with Windows XP and Windows 7 machines. I'm not sure how it would work on a non-domain network or if you were on no network at all.

```
Public Function GetComputerUserName()
    Dim objnet As Object
    Set objnet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    GetComputerUserName = objnet.UserName
    Set objnet = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way is to use a Windows API call:

```
'This line must go at top of module
Private Declare Function WNetGetUser& Lib "Mpr" Alias _
                "WNetGetUserA" (lpName As Any, ByVal lpUserName$, lpnLength&)


Function GetUserName() As String
Const MaxNameLength As Long = 256
Dim ret As Long, UserName As String

    UserName = Space(256)
    ret = WNetGetUser(ByVal 0&, UserName, MaxNameLength)
    If ret = 0 Then
        'Success - strip off the null.
        UserName = Left(UserName, InStr(UserName, Chr(0)) - 1)
    Else
        UserName = ""
    End If

    GetUserName = LCase$(UserName)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can;

```
user = Environ$("USERNAME")
```

Comment: Only use `Environ()` to get the user name if you don't care about security.

Comment: To expand on @HansUp's point: `Environ$("USERNAME")` simply returns the value of the USERNAME environment variable.  This gets set to the windows username automatically at logon, but it's dead easy to circumvent.  Just open a command window and type `Set USERNAME=usertoimpersonate`.  Now `Environ$("USERNAME")` will return the string: `usertoimpersonate`

Comment: That being said, `Environ$("USERNAME")` is a handy shortcut as long as you understand all of the implications

Comment: `Environ()` is sandboxed by default, which means you can't use it in a query and may need to jump through extra hoops to use it in the control source of a form or report control.  That undermines its handiness.  The methods suggested in your and Harlan's answers are both easy to use once you know about them and are not so trivially easy to circumvent.